# what type of device drivers are available in linux

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

The different types of device drivers used in linux are character device and block device. Is there another classification?

Answer (score 1):

In the traditional classification, there are three kinds of device:

- block device
- character device
- others!

As you can figure out exploring `/dev`, there are devices which are not block neither char device. For example, physical net interfaces are not represented by a file in the filesystem and you cannot `read(1)` and `write(1)` from them the same way you can with your keyboard or your soundcard. The only interfaces present in `/dev` are virtual interfaces like `tun` or `tap`.

There are also other classifications the kernel linux uses, called "classes". You can see the list of classes under `/sys/class`.
From the documentation of the kernel:

> Each device class defines a set of semantics and a programming interface
>   that devices of that class adhere to. Device drivers are the
>   implementation of that programming interface for a particular device on
>   a particular bus.

[Documentation/driver-model/class.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/driver-model/class.txt)